# How to fix chart not starting at zero

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have tried putting the scales inside of plugins, I've tried moving everything around. I cannot seem to figure out why this isn't working.

```
let lineChart = new Chart(line, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Workout Duration In Minutes',
                    backgroundColor: 'red',
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    data: durations,
                    fill: false,
                }, ],
            },
            options: {
                plugins: {
                    responsive: true,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Time Spent Working Out (Last 7 days)',
                    },
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                        },
                    }],
                },
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using v3 since in v2 this is the correct syntax, in v3 the scales are no arrays anymore but just objects, for all changes you can read the migration guide (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```